# How to register javascript variables in wp_localize_script?

Tags: php, javascript, localization, wp-localize-script

When translating PHP-strings with variables, I use the following approach:

```
sprintf(__('Some text <b>%s</b>, more text.','my-plugin' ), $somestring);
```

When translating javascript strings, I use this approach:

```
wp_register_script( 'my_script', 'my_file.js' );
$translation_array = array(
     'original_string' => __( 'Original string', 'my-plugin' )
);
wp_localize_script( 'my_script', 'script_strings', $translation_array );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script' );
```

But how can I include javascript variables in the translated javascript strings, if I want to translate a string like the following?

```
var somevariable = 'somecontent';
console.log('This is my original string from ' + somevariable + ' some more text');
```

Thanks,

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610406) is what you are looking for. However, it's not a WordPress question since you are going to do it on client's browser.

Comment: Thanks. What's the generally used approach for this? would you normally just split the string in 2 translations, or would you add a function that works like sprintf does in PHP like suggested in the other question?

Comment: JS doesn't have a function like `sprint`, so you either have to create one for it or use a library ( in the provided link ), or you have to use find and replace or `.format` ( also included in the link ).

Comment: Yeah. I get that. I wast just wondering whether the best approach would be to use the approach from the link, or just simply add the needed strings as 2 translations.. 'This is my original string from ' & ' some more text' - then concat them with the variable.